# I am hosting my website (php files) in GAE. The app.yaml file is not routing the pages of my site. Error: No Found

Tags: google-app-engine, php-7.2, vs-web-site-project, app.yaml

My site has 8 pages and it is written in php: https://intercultural.appspot.com  After deploying in GAE, it can load and dislpay the index.php page. However, does not display the other pages when I click on other links: Error: No Found  The requested URL /file.php was not found on this server.

Here is the directory of my file: hightlighted in blue are the pages of my site.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQc5q.jpg)

Here is my app.yaml file:

```html
runtime: php72 </b>

handlers:
# Serve a directory as a static resource.
- url: /styles
  static_dir: styles
  
# Serve images as static resources.
- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg)$
  
# Serve your app through a front controller at index.php or public/index.php.
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: /(.+\.php)$

# I add the "/" to url bellow as suggested but still get same error
- url: /.*
  script: auto
  secure: always
```

Although it displays the site address in the browser, it says: Error: No Found  The requested URL /file.php was not found on this server.

What is missing in the app.yaml file to route properly to the other pages of my site?

Comment: Please edit your question and add copy/paste your code using the code format instead of screenshots. Please check this article :https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The URL for your final entry in the app.yaml should be `url: /.*` (with slash). This is necessary to match URLs of `https://intercultural.appspot.com/*`. You can see an example in the [app.yaml reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref).

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your reply. I added the "/" to url: /.* However, I still get the same error: Error: Not Found The requested URL /image.php was not found on this server. 
According to app.yaml Configuration File for PHP 7.2, there is no need for the "/" see here please
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/config/appref

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed it.
The main problem was in the php version. I thought my code was written in php7.2 but actually it was php5.5, hence, the app.yaml didn't work properly.
Here is the app.yaml file:

This is my app.yaml file

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /styles
  static_dir: styles

- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg)$
  application_readable: true

- url: /
  script: index.php
  secure: always

- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
  secure: always
```